# Ruby Array Ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

```
(2011..1995).to_a
```

returns an array

```
(Time.now.year.to_i..1995).to_a
```

doesn't.  Why?

Comment: both of these statements return empty array for me. ruby 1.8.7p302

Comment: Both return an empty array, as Eimantas says. However, if you you reverse the items in the range so that 1995 is first, they both return the expected array.  Ranges aren't really meant going backwards.

Comment: you should indicate which Ruby version are you using

Comment: (Time.now.year.to_i).downto(1995).to_a

Answer (score 13, accepted):

try

```
> 2011.downto(1995).to_a
=> [2011, 2010, 2009, 2008, 2007, 2006, 2005, 2004, 2003, 2002, 2001, 2000, 1999, 1998, 1997, 1996, 1995]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this

(Time.now.year.to_i).downto(1995).to_a

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that either work. Here's irb on WinXP...

```
irb(main):009:0> (2011..1995).to_a
=> []
irb(main):010:0> (Time.now.year.to_i..1995).to_a
=> []
irb(main):011:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

(1995..Time.now.year.to_i).to_a works. End should large than begin.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot replicate your results. Both of these expressions return an array.

Of course, since both of the ranges are empty, the expressions will always return an *empty* array, but that's not relevant to your question.